# Remove margin/padding between compound drawable, android

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android and I want to create dynamic forms with java. When I set compound drawable to EditText then it shows space between left border of EditText   and drawable as in picture. How can we remove this space?[image]

Comment: show your code please

Comment: userDetailsFormFields[fieldPos].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.
                        search_bus_fragment_input_bg);
                //Set padding  for EditText
                userDetailsFormFields[fieldPos].setPadding(0,0,0,0);// 
                //Set compound drawables for each field  from typed array.
              userDetailsFormFields[fieldPos].
                        setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(iconSets.
                                getResourceId(i, -1), 0, 0, 0);
               userDetailsFormFields[fieldPos].setHint(hintResource[i]);   //loop generates indx

Comment: Well, I just fixed it. When I made array of resources like int[] icons = {R.drawable.icon1}; and used it in same way then it worked fine.